# Create large numbers of objects efficiently

Tags: php, performance

**edit:** wrong assumptions were made by my un-perfect self when I posted this question and I feel **this question might be misleading**.
The efficiency problem actually turned out to be unrelated to push_array.

The comments were helpful in helping me to understand that:
1)this should not take so long, and 
2) diagnosing efficiency problems with microtime() is a good practice.
**end edit**

I am creating ~1400 objects in a test scenario. I think ~1400 will be within a magnitude of typical use.

```
public $t = Array();   
...
for(...){    
    code...   
    for(...){    
        array_push($this->t, new T($i, $str));    //<--this line slows program.
        count++;    
    }   
    code...
}
```

Unfortunately the script is taking about 90 seconds to run. If I comment out the *one line* of code with array_push, the script runs in about 1/6 the time, about 15 seconds.

The inner loop count varies, but averages about 3 to 15 cycles with one new object for each cycle.

Questions:
I am not an expert in PHP. I would like to know:
1) if it would help (and if so, how) to allocate memory space beforehand.
2) if there are any efficiency steps I should be taking that would help the script run faster or a data structure that would be more efficient then an array of objects. The newly created objects currently have two attributes, an integer and a string representing a single word (roughly averaging ~10 characters).

**edit:**
This is the constructor:

```
class T{
    public $line; 
    public $text;
    function __construct($ln, $txt){
        $this->line = $ln;
        $this->text = $txt;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you replace that line with `$this->t[] = new T($i, $str);`, and what does the constructor of `T` do?

Comment: What exactly is the `T` constructor doing?

Comment: There is http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php, but I don't think that'll help. Only 1400 array inserts isn't going to cost you 90 seconds (each insert is probably O(logn), not O(n), and shouldn't have to realloc each time presuming exponential capacity growth). I'd think that the costly operation is the instantiation of type `T`. What is `T` and what does its constructor do?

Comment: Something else is going on here that you aren't revealing.  I'm using PHP 5.4.3 on a Core i3 and my test scenario using both `array_push()` and `$arr[] = ...` syntax completed in 0.02s for 1400 new objects comprised of just an integer and string (constructor did nothing but assign the values to its properties).

Comment: @Sven I tried an it was identical at 90 seconds.

Comment: @JohnR: Can you paste the constructor's code in your question?  That will help determine where the problem lies.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem in the last project I've been working on - the best option is using splitting the construtor actions to functions , and then using microtime() you'll be able which one makes the code run slowly

Comment: Thanks for posting the constructor. That isn't the problem either. Please post a complete working program that is as small as possible that replicates your code and performance problem. Any of the segments you snipped might be at fault, or something that happens far down the line. (For example, if you comment out the array_push, then the array might be empty, so later down the line, a costly operation on 1400 items reduces to nothing)

Comment: @JohnR: Thank you for posting the constructor, but there's nothing there that would cause a performance issue.  It's basically identical to my test case, which completed in 0.02s.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime depends on few different factors :

- The server your using to run the script
- Code efficiency of course - here's a great article about [writing efficient php code](http://the-dro.com/web-design/programming/40-tips-for-optimizing-your-php-code/)

Of course there are more factors , but from previous exprience it shouldn't take that long , but still , the information I've got about the objects you're creating is not broad enough so I could detect where the problem is.
By the way, using PHP Accelerators such as APC or xcache might improve your code runtime.